# IllegalArgument Exception in Base64 File Upload in Android

Tags: java, android, base64, android-webservice

I got exception in base64 File Upload in Android. I refered so many thread in Stackoverflow, but no posts solves my problem. Please help me out from this issue as soon as possible.

I'm pasting my logcat error here

```
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): Process: com.ipage.fieldexecutive, PID: 14445
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 76: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCABiAGIDASIA
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):   uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD+AAAn
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): p/nkjPf0/UdzVyCAkE89QfyJB7dOO/TI5JBpbeDqSPTHHPU5z7dPpzyDWxbwd8enb3/l/nOaA/r8
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): /Py/PXR3bb2+ATjnj9Cee/68ZI6kYratbY89f4fX/b9/88+hp9vanHIOeOMf7WOuP07eoPNdLYad
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): vVndgiDaM/xFvnxtU4JHABYcA55+WtaNGriKns6UXOVrvtGKvec29IwileUpNJK13rdxOcKcZTnJ
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): RjHRttfLr36fmtRmn2LzMyqPurvckgAIpfceTycc7epGcc8D6V/Zh8e+BPh38VNH1nxd4Jk8c7rq
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): 3s9HhS8uLP8A4R/VZLhTa+J3aFSJ005wHNtJ+7c5DE4Jr50PnRTC1RW/eSoFRAWMh3FRjb8x3Hoo
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): 5J7HjH278LPh/ongnwdf+NdVt/tuoXmnTXzPPEY5bTTzE3m2KpnIOYt/mMBICRjGDn6jDZbhMPhX
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): Gdq2JrU5qdZLmhT55KMYYdTg0pJJOVacXNTbjS5VGbl5U8ZVlUvGypwnBqL+1HVuUndXvo1Bact+
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): ZtaH2R4U+If7NVl8R/E2m+DtXvpPiV8avFV34Q8ZeKV0fVxYeE7DxBcMmoa5cSPB9hmgsJmErgyh
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): GUfeC7mr85/jD4H1X9n341eJfBfja307xJp97LPqeheINM1exuodY0W5vJhZau66dNOlpNdxJ5j2
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): MrCeIMA6AgmqFr8eo/A3hz4iN4b8u7h8d2Wq+Hm0eSFYm0yHUlcHWLfUCj3BuIQcJEpU8KfMDYNf
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): N+j2Wr63Z2kcc1xqGo/bR+9vLmaV/s+2QKhlneRo4t3TJ2gkcHBJ5MoqY3LMzhVpxhN0ppVoVqVK
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): rSlRk5q06daEqc6bS1TV72sk4s6MZOlisLKM6koucE4TpznTnFptpQlCfOpO90r/AMrs7pn2/wCC
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): Jvhf4jjkitbF2u0jV3TbdbY9zbR+8ZAjEFcbQ2Rz3znsbb4d6Xd3cr22sfZLfgrC0LYT55M4Zjz0
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): XHfqckk1g/D7wrB4Z0G2iG1rq4jWe4kCrkPKql4wwJ3KjL8rZ5B5BPTc8SeJLHwxpNxqF/HPLCiO
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): SttDLLIQpz9yEFyemPXkcnLD9Kq8T5FUwrpZrwLwzi8Fh4yquGX4ark2Prziptc2PwVaM0qjjrHk
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): cbtOzbbXydHK8wVZ/U+Icyw9WvOFP2mJqQxmHpRlNpy9hXg17trtqSlbS7szmYDpT3tjaabfC8XU
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): b2502ymkRoBLeWfmfaI2EmPLCCMlXc7X52sSa7OPTJraVreVD5iBC4XDKAfMwdwOMH5cHJ4I64Br
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): 6B1v9n3wx4++G2leLtAsofAOs6FbrrVvpVlMdQj157q3iXN1czOjWDzLI10+EJEpMWOXJ+bNI1DV
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): ZJLHS9avYtJn1S6vbC0nhliuzOdMdg4kyV8rCIGySSSQOoIH5rwvieGONKmYYOGFxWU51icXToZN
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): h8BNVcpp1qidOll+KhjsRVxMJV66glj/AO0J0qdOpJzw6VLmn99xLkef8IrB1sXUw2My6WG9rXxF
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): VuGKnCEnKpiqaowjG1Kmm5YeWGpzlJRcZyVRcvTC0fHAPQdP+Be31/Xk9ipv+Eg0KLMT3Jd4z5bN
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): tX5mRpFZuHI+YrnjjGeTiivnppwnOEk1KEpQkrN+9GUovVLXWP4rV6siLUoqS2aTXo1K34R/Fdbn
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): 5L29vk9OmP5n2+vfHoRjI3rW29v7v/s3+f8ADHG74S8I654v8QaT4X8Oabc6rrOt6hZabp1lZ289
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): xNNdXlyttDmO3imkWMSOhlk2ERpudsha/TL9tb/gmj8Vv+CeXgX9m/X/AI+xw2njL9oLQtb1zQ/C
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): tleW+pWFpaaPfWltKbqeG2tbqzm2XsUiRXURZmLhTtXNbYWg8XiKOHjKNN1ZxhzzvyxTbTk7Jt2V
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): moxTnJtxinJWacrQcrN8qvZ2TfxLvZXsr30V1rpJnwD4Q+HfiLxXZ6jf6Zax/Y9MUm5nuZRboWWJ
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): pUSNpF2uZFQgBW3FiFAya5hrfU4rp1mtZ1ETbY4xDKY4l3PlY3CDcpPzbjk8kZ4bP2TLewaH4H8P
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): eF9K220t1bLceJbWM7Q2owXUhtGkBZi5EDrgnaQuPl+UE4unWkd/PHFLAkjSOkXzZ2ne5U7myAF6
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): ZPQDrzmv2jKuDMsllNKjSx8qOLqONTF1qlFSdeTa5KSgqilSoUZfw4qUnOSVaqnPkjH4jG57W9rW
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): UqMXSi7QjzNSjyuSbd/icnG70VleKlZtv558OxCXxJ4ZklU7l1zTEYMvJX7WCUZT2bH1wTkkjNfo
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): /wCOVj/4QvxcqIEjGhahtRRgKPIkHABHTk47ZPOS1eH6p8MtPgutONhZ2SXguIJkuIXBnS/SU+R5
02-07 19:18:11.536: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): ADt5nOwhsMQcDBOa+lNe+F3i23+FWpXmranbG41XSZ45n1S/tbVo
```

And my Async Task Class

```
  public class AddShopTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      private ProgressDialog pDialog1;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog1 = new ProgressDialog(AddShopActivity.this);
        pDialog1.setMessage(getString(R.string.ip_updating_the_server));
       pDialog1.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog1.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog1.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String shopName = mShopNameEditText.getText().toString();
        String shopDescription = mShopServiceDescription.getText().toString();
        String landMark = mShopAddress.getText().toString();
        String userType = "2";
        String shopMobileNo = mShopMobileNumber.getText().toString();
        String shopEmailId = mShopEmailId.getText().toString();
        String shopPicture = encodeImageToB64Format();
        String createdOn = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return HttpConnectionUtils.getAddShopResponse(shopName, shopPicture, landMark,
                mShopCityName, shopMobileNo, shopEmailId, shopDescription, "paymentDetails",
                createdOn, "78.37492398", "87.238829323", userType, shopPicture);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog1.dismiss();
        if (result != null && !result.trim().equals("")) {
            try {
                JSONObject loginResponseObj = new JSONObject(result);
                String loginState = loginResponseObj.getString("result");

                if (loginState.equals("success")) {

                    Toast.makeText(AddShopActivity.this, "Shop Added Successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    iPreferenceUtils.clearAllPreferences(AddShopActivity.this);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddShopActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        } else {
            Crouton.makeText(AddShopActivity.this, R.string.err_check_your_connection,
                    Style.ALERT).show();
        }
    }
}

private String encodeImageToB64Format() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    profilePhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageByte = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodeShopImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageByte, Base64.NO_PADDING);

    return encodeShopImage;
}
```

Comment: What are the lines of the stack trace *below* what you've posted? We don't know which call threw the exception. (I suspect it was getAddShopResponse, but we don't know what that does either.)

Answer (score 1):

Position 76 sounds like end of line - and almost is. Base64 text is often split in lines less than 80 characters, thus adding newline characters. For some decoders one first has to remove \r and \n.

```
String encodeShopImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageByte,
        Base64.NO_PADDING|Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Padding causes trailing fillers like '---', wrapping causes line-endings.

or

```
return encodeShopImage.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9/+]", "");
```

Crudely removes all non-Base64 characters.